# Symfony3 - What is the good way to handle file upload / edit?

Tags: forms, file, upload, symfony

The cookbook explanation code works very well with the NewAction() controller but how to edit a form who have a file with this technic ?

this edit controller always erase file even if it does not exist. thats a problem when I just want to edit text but not the file itself...

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Model $model)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($model);
    $editForm = $this->createForm(ModelType::class, $model);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

            $file = $model->getPicture();
            $fileName = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

            $uploadDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../web/' . Model::UPLOAD_DIR;
            $file->move($uploadDir, $fileName);

            $model->setPicture($fileName);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($model);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('my_route', array('id' => $model->getId()));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, did you fix that? How?

Comment: if (null === $this->getFile()) {   return;  }  In the upload() method in the entity class